# What is wrong in computing header for ISO8583?

Tags: java, transactions, finance, iso8583

I need to implement or integrate the ISO8583, using Java. I am using jpos for the implementation. In code, everything seems fine; but at server level it's identified the format is not as per expectations. Where network team is saying header is not their.

The code is as below (updated):

```
   // Load the ISO 8583 packager from the resources folder
                InputStream is = ISO8583MessageHandler.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("iso93ascii.xml");
                if (is == null) {
                    throw new IllegalArgumentException("iso8583.xml is not found in resources!");
                }
                // Load the ISO 8583 packager
                GenericPackager packager = new GenericPackager(ISO8583MessageHandler.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("iso93ascii.xml"));
                packager.setLogger(LOGGER, "client");

                // PostChannel for 2 bytes header
                PostChannel channel = new PostChannel(serverIP, serverPort, packager);
                channel.setLogger(LOGGER, "client");

                ISOMsg isoMsg = new ISOMsg();
                isoMsg.setPackager(packager);
                isoMsg.setMTI("1804");
                isoMsg.set(11, TransactionUtils.generateSTAN()); // Unique STAN
                isoMsg.set(12, new SimpleDateFormat("yyMMddHHmmss").format(new Date())); // yyMMddHHmmss
                isoMsg.set(24, "831"); // Function code

                // Serialize the message once
                isoMsg.recalcBitMap();
                byte[] packedMessage = isoMsg.pack();


                // Prepare the header
                /*byte[] header = new byte[2];
                int length = (packedMessage.length);
                System.out.println("Length " + length);
                header[0] = (byte) (length >> 8); // High byte
                header[1] = (byte) (length);      // Low byte

                isoMsg.setHeader(header);
                byte[] finalPackedMessage = isoMsg.pack();*/

                // Now dump the full message
                System.out.println("Message Hex Dump:: ");
                System.out.println(ISOUtil.hexString(packedMessage));
                System.out.println("Message ASCII Dump:: ");
                System.out.println(TransactionUtils.hexToAscii(ISOUtil.hexString(packedMessage)));
//            System.out.println("Full Message Hex Dump:: ");
//            System.out.println(TransactionUtils.toFormattedHexDump(fullMessage));

                channel.connect();
                channel.send(isoMsg);

                System.out.println("ISO Network Management Call Sent...");

                ISOMsg response = channel.receive();
                System.out.println("Received Network Management Response from the Server!");
                printISOMessage(response);
```

The code above is for Network Management call (sing-on). As per the integration document the protocol requirement is something like:
[image]

The header requirement:

[image]

The iso93ascii.xml file:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<!DOCTYPE isopackager SYSTEM "genericpackager.dtd">

<!-- ISO 8583:1993 (ASCII) field descriptions for GenericPackager -->

<isopackager headerLength="2">
  <isofield
      id="0"
      length="4"
      name="Message Type Indicator"
      class="org.jpos.iso.IFA_NUMERIC"/>
  <isofield
      id="1"
      length="64"
      name="Bitmap"
      class="org.jpos.iso.IFA_BITMAP"/>
  <isofield
      id="2"
      length="24"
      name="Primary Account number"
      class="org.jpos.iso.IFA_LLNUM"/>
  <isofield
      id="3"
      length="6"
      name="Processing Code"
      class="org.jpos.iso.IFA_NUMERIC"/>
  <isofield
      id="4"
      length="12"
      name="Amount, Transaction"
      class="org.jpos.iso.IFA_NUMERIC"/>
  <isofield
      id="5"
      length="12"
      name="Amount, Reconciliation"
      class="org.jpos.iso.IFA_NUMERIC"/>
  <isofield
      id="6"
      length="12"
      name="Amount, Cardholder billing"
      class="org.jpos.iso.IFA_NUMERIC"/>
  <isofield
      id="7"
      length="10"
      name="Date and time, transmission"
      class="org.jpos.iso.IFA_NUMERIC"/>
  <isofield
      id="8"
      length="8"
      name="Amount, Cardholder billing fee"
      class="org.jpos.iso.IFA_NUMERIC"/>
  <isofield
      id="9"
      length="8"
      name="Conversion rate, Reconciliation"
      class="org.jpos.iso.IFA_NUMERIC"/>
  <isofield
      id="10"
      length="8"
      name="Conversion rate, Cardholder billing"
      class="org.jpos.iso.IFA_NUMERIC"/>
  <isofield
      id="11"
      length="6"
      name="Systems trace audit number"
      class="org.jpos.iso.IFA_NUMERIC"/>
  <isofield
      id="12"
      length="12"
      name="Date and time, Local transaction"
      class="org.jpos.iso.IFA_NUMERIC"/>
  <isofield
      id="13"
      length="4"
      name="Date, Effective"
      class="org.jpos.iso.IFA_NUMERIC"/>
  <isofield
      id="14"
      length="4"
      name="Date, Expiration"
      class="org.jpos.iso.IFA_NUMERIC"/>
  <isofield
      id="15"
      length="6"
      name="Date, Settlement"
      class="org.jpos.iso.IFA_NUMERIC"/>
  <isofield
      id="16"
      length="4"
      name="Date, Conversion"
      class="org.jpos.iso.IFA_NUMERIC"/>
  <isofield
      id="17"
      length="4"
      name="Date, Capture"
      class="org.jpos.iso.IFA_NUMERIC"/>
  <isofield
      id="18"
      length="4"
      name="Merchant type"
      class="org.jpos.iso.IFA_NUMERIC"/>
  <isofield
      id="19"
      length="3"
      name="Country code, Acquiring institution"
      class="org.jpos.iso.IFA_NUMERIC"/>
  <isofield
      id="20"
      length="3"
      name="Country code, Primary account number"
      class="org.jpos.iso.IFA_NUMERIC"/>
  <isofield
      id="21"
      length="3"
      name="Country code, Forwarding institution"
      class="org.jpos.iso.IFA_NUMERIC"/>
  <isofield
      id="22"
      length="12"
      name="Point of service data code"
      class="org.jpos.iso.IF_CHAR"/>
  <isofield
      id="23"
      length="3"
      name="Card sequence number"
      class="org.jpos.iso.IFA_NUMERIC"/>
  <isofield
      id="24"
      length="3"
      name="Function code"
      class="org.jpos.iso.IFA_NUMERIC"/>
  <isofield
      id="25"
      length="4"
      name="Message reason code"
      class="org.jpos.iso.IFA_NUMERIC"/>
  <isofield
      id="26"
      length="4"
      name="Card acceptor business code"
      class="org.jpos.iso.IFA_NUMERIC"/>
  <isofield
      id="27"
      length="1"
      name="Approval code length"
      class="org.jpos.iso.IFA_NUMERIC"/>
  <isofield
      id="28"
      length="6"
      name="Date, Reconciliation"
      class="org.jpos.iso.IFA_NUMERIC"/>
  <isofield
      id="29"
      length="3"
      name="Reconciliation indicator"
      class="org.jpos.iso.IFA_NUMERIC"/>
  <isofield
      id="30"
      length="24"
      name="Amounts, original"
      class="org.jpos.iso.IFA_NUMERIC"/>
  <isofield
      id="31"
      length="99"
      name="Acquirer reference data"
      class="org.jpos.iso.IFA_LLCHAR"/>
  <isofield
      id="32"
      length="11"
      name="Acquirer institution identification code"
      class="org.jpos.iso.IFA_LLNUM"/>
  <isofield
      id="33"
      length="11"
      name="Forwarding institution identification code"
      class="org.jpos.iso.IFA_LLNUM"/>
  <isofield
      id="34"
      length="28"
      name="Primary account number, extended"
      class="org.jpos.iso.IFA_LLCHAR"/>
  <isofield
      id="35"
      length="37"
      name="Track 2 data"
      class="org.jpos.iso.IFA_LLCHAR"/>
  <isofield
      id="36"
      length="104"
      name="Track 3 data"
      class="org.jpos.iso.IFA_LLLCHAR"/>
  <isofield
      id="37"
      length="12"
      name="Retrieval reference number"
      class="org.jpos.iso.IF_CHAR"/>
  <isofield
      id="38"
      length="6"
      name="Approval code"
      class="org.jpos.iso.IF_CHAR"/>
  <isofield
      id="39"
      length="3"
      name="Action code"
      class="org.jpos.iso.IFA_NUMERIC"/>
  <isofield
      id="40"
      length="3"
      name="Service code"
      class="org.jpos.iso.IFA_NUMERIC"/>
  <isofield
      id="41"
      length="8"
      name="Card acceptor terminal identification"
      class="org.jpos.iso.IF_CHAR"/>
  <isofield
      id="42"
      length="15"
      name="Card acceptor identification code"
      class="org.jpos.iso.IF_CHAR"/>
  <isofield
      id="43"
      length="99"
      name="Card acceptor name/location"
      class="org.jpos.iso.IFA_LLCHAR"/>
  <isofield
      id="44"
      length="99"
      name="Additional response data"
      class="org.jpos.iso.IFA_LLCHAR"/>
  <isofield
      id="45"
      length="76"
      name="Track 1 data"
      class="org.jpos.iso.IFA_LLCHAR"/>
  <isofield
      id="46"
      length="204"
      name="Amounts, Fees"
      class="org.jpos.iso.IFA_LLLCHAR"/>
  <isofield
      id="47"
      length="999"
      name="Additional data - national"
      class="org.jpos.iso.IFA_LLLCHAR"/>
  <isofield
      id="48"
      length="999"
      name="Additional data - private"
      class="org.jpos.iso.IFA_LLLCHAR"/>
  <isofield
      id="49"
      length="3"
      name="Currency code, Transaction"
      class="org.jpos.iso.IF_CHAR"/>
  <isofield
      id="50"
      length="3"
      name="Currency code, Reconciliation"
      class="org.jpos.iso.IF_CHAR"/>
  <isofield
      id="51"
      length="3"
      name="Currency code, Cardholder billing"
      class="org.jpos.iso.IF_CHAR"/>
  <isofield
      id="52"
      length="8"
      name="Personal identification number [PIN] data"
      class="org.jpos.iso.IFA_BINARY"/>
  <isofield
      id="53"
      length="48"
      name="Security related control information"
      class="org.jpos.iso.IFA_LLBINARY"/>
  <isofield
      id="54"
      length="120"
      name="Amounts, additional"
      class="org.jpos.iso.IFA_LLLCHAR"/>
  <isofield
      id="55"
      length="255"
      name="IC card system related data"
      class="org.jpos.iso.IFA_LLLBINARY"/>
  <isofield
      id="56"
      length="35"
      name="Original data elements"
      class="org.jpos.iso.IFA_LLNUM"/>
  <isofield
      id="57"
      length="3"
      name="Authorization life cycle code"
      class="org.jpos.iso.IFA_NUMERIC"/>
  <isofield
      id="58"
      length="11"
      name="Authorizing agent institution Id Code"
      class="org.jpos.iso.IFA_LLNUM"/>
  <isofield
      id="59"
      length="999"
      name="Transport data"
      class="org.jpos.iso.IFA_LLLCHAR"/>
  <isofield
      id="60"
      length="999"
      name="Reserved for national use"
      class="org.jpos.iso.IFA_LLLCHAR"/>
  <isofield
      id="61"
      length="999"
      name="Reserved for national use"
      class="org.jpos.iso.IFA_LLLCHAR"/>
  <isofield
      id="62"
      length="999"
      name="Reserved for private use"
      class="org.jpos.iso.IFA_LLLCHAR"/>
  <isofield
      id="63"
      length="999"
      name="Reserved for private use"
      class="org.jpos.iso.IFA_LLLCHAR"/>
  <isofield
      id="64"
      length="8"
      name="Message authentication code field"
      class="org.jpos.iso.IFA_BINARY"/>
  <isofield
      id="65"
      length="8"
      name="Reserved for ISO use"
      class="org.jpos.iso.IFA_BINARY"/>
  <isofield
      id="66"
      length="204"
      name="Amounts, original fees"
      class="org.jpos.iso.IFA_LLLCHAR"/>
  <isofield
      id="67"
      length="2"
      name="Extended payment data"
      class="org.jpos.iso.IFA_NUMERIC"/>
  <isofield
      id="68"
      length="3"
      name="Country code, receiving institution"
      class="org.jpos.iso.IFA_NUMERIC"/>
  <isofield
      id="69"
      length="3"
      name="Country code, settlement institution"
      class="org.jpos.iso.IFA_NUMERIC"/>
  <isofield
      id="70"
      length="3"
      name="Country code, authorizing agent Inst."
      class="org.jpos.iso.IFA_NUMERIC"/>
  <isofield
      id="71"
      length="8"
      name="Message number"
      class="org.jpos.iso.IFA_NUMERIC"/>
  <isofield
      id="72"
      length="999"
      name="Data record"
      class="org.jpos.iso.IFA_LLLCHAR"/>
  <isofield
      id="73"
      length="6"
      name="Date, action"
      class="org.jpos.iso.IFA_NUMERIC"/>
  <isofield
      id="74"
      length="10"
      name="Credits, number"
      class="org.jpos.iso.IFA_NUMERIC"/>
  <isofield
      id="75"
      length="10"
      name="Credits, reversal number"
      class="org.jpos.iso.IFA_NUMERIC"/>
  <isofield
      id="76"
      length="10"
      name="Debits, number"
      class="org.jpos.iso.IFA_NUMERIC"/>
  <isofield
      id="77"
      length="10"
      name="Debits, reversal number"
      class="org.jpos.iso.IFA_NUMERIC"/>
  <isofield
      id="78"
      length="10"
      name="Transfer, number"
      class="org.jpos.iso.IFA_NUMERIC"/>
  <isofield
      id="79"
      length="10"
      name="Transfer, reversal number"
      class="org.jpos.iso.IFA_NUMERIC"/>
  <isofield
      id="80"
      length="10"
      name="Inquiries, number"
      class="org.jpos.iso.IFA_NUMERIC"/>
  <isofield
      id="81"
      length="10"
      name="Authorizations, number"
      class="org.jpos.iso.IFA_NUMERIC"/>
  <isofield
      id="82"
      length="10"
      name="Inquiries, reversal number"
      class="org.jpos.iso.IFA_NUMERIC"/>
  <isofield
      id="83"
      length="10"
      name="Payments, number"
      class="org.jpos.iso.IFA_NUMERIC"/>
  <isofield
      id="84"
      length="10"
      name="Payments, reversal number"
      class="org.jpos.iso.IFA_NUMERIC"/>
  <isofield
      id="85"
      length="10"
      name="Fee collections, number"
      class="org.jpos.iso.IFA_NUMERIC"/>
  <isofield
      id="86"
      length="16"
      name="Credits, amount"
      class="org.jpos.iso.IFA_NUMERIC"/>
  <isofield
      id="87"
      length="16"
      name="Credits, reversal amount"
      class="org.jpos.iso.IFA_NUMERIC"/>
  <isofield
      id="88"
      length="16"
      name="Debits, amount"
      class="org.jpos.iso.IFA_NUMERIC"/>
  <isofield
      id="89"
      length="16"
      name="Debits, reversal amount"
      class="org.jpos.iso.IFA_NUMERIC"/>
  <isofield
      id="90"
      length="10"
      name="Authorizations, reversal number"
      class="org.jpos.iso.IFA_NUMERIC"/>
  <isofield
      id="91"
      length="3"
      name="Country code, transaction Dest. Inst."
      class="org.jpos.iso.IFA_NUMERIC"/>
  <isofield
      id="92"
      length="3"
      name="Country code, transaction Orig. Inst."
      class="org.jpos.iso.IFA_NUMERIC"/>
  <isofield
      id="93"
      length="11"
      name="Transaction Dest. Inst. Id code"
      class="org.jpos.iso.IFA_LLNUM"/>
  <isofield
      id="94"
      length="11"
      name="Transaction Orig. Inst. Id code"
      class="org.jpos.iso.IFA_LLNUM"/>
  <isofield
      id="95"
      length="99"
      name="Card issuer reference data"
      class="org.jpos.iso.IFA_LLCHAR"/>
  <isofield
      id="96"
      length="999"
      name="Key management data"
      class="org.jpos.iso.IFA_LLLBINARY"/>
  <isofield
      id="97"
      length="17"
      name="Amount, Net reconciliation"
      class="org.jpos.iso.IFA_AMOUNT"/>
  <isofield
      id="98"
      length="25"
      name="Payee"
      class="org.jpos.iso.IF_CHAR"/>
  <isofield
      id="99"
      length="11"
      name="Settlement institution Id code"
      class="org.jpos.iso.IFA_LLCHAR"/>
  <isofield
      id="100"
      length="11"
      name="Receiving institution Id code"
      class="org.jpos.iso.IFA_LLNUM"/>
  <isofield
      id="101"
      length="17"
      name="File name"
      class="org.jpos.iso.IFA_LLCHAR"/>
  <isofield
      id="102"
      length="28"
      name="Account identification 1"
      class="org.jpos.iso.IFA_LLCHAR"/>
  <isofield
      id="103"
      length="28"
      name="Account identification 2"
      class="org.jpos.iso.IFA_LLCHAR"/>
  <isofield
      id="104"
      length="100"
      name="Transaction description"
      class="org.jpos.iso.IFA_LLLCHAR"/>
  <isofield
      id="105"
      length="16"
      name="Credits, Chargeback amount"
      class="org.jpos.iso.IFA_NUMERIC"/>
  <isofield
      id="106"
      length="16"
      name="Debits, Chargeback amount"
      class="org.jpos.iso.IFA_NUMERIC"/>
  <isofield
      id="107"
      length="10"
      name="Credits, Chargeback number"
      class="org.jpos.iso.IFA_NUMERIC"/>
  <isofield
      id="108"
      length="10"
      name="Debits, Chargeback number"
      class="org.jpos.iso.IFA_NUMERIC"/>
  <isofield
      id="109"
      length="84"
      name="Credits, Fee amounts"
      class="org.jpos.iso.IFA_LLCHAR"/>
  <isofield
      id="110"
      length="84"
      name="Debits, Fee amounts"
      class="org.jpos.iso.IFA_LLCHAR"/>
  <isofield
      id="111"
      length="999"
      name="Reserved for ISO use"
      class="org.jpos.iso.IFA_LLLCHAR"/>
  <isofield
      id="112"
      length="999"
      name="Reserved for ISO use"
      class="org.jpos.iso.IFA_LLLCHAR"/>
  <isofield
      id="113"
      length="999"
      name="Reserved for ISO use"
      class="org.jpos.iso.IFA_LLLCHAR"/>
  <isofield
      id="114"
      length="999"
      name="Reserved for ISO use"
      class="org.jpos.iso.IFA_LLLCHAR"/>
  <isofield
      id="115"
      length="999"
      name="Reserved for ISO use"
      class="org.jpos.iso.IFA_LLLCHAR"/>
  <isofield
      id="116"
      length="999"
      name="Reserved for national use"
      class="org.jpos.iso.IFA_LLLCHAR"/>
  <isofield
      id="117"
      length="999"
      name="Reserved for national use"
      class="org.jpos.iso.IFA_LLLCHAR"/>
  <isofield
      id="118"
      length="999"
      name="Reserved for national use"
      class="org.jpos.iso.IFA_LLLCHAR"/>
  <isofield
      id="119"
      length="999"
      name="Reserved for national use"
      class="org.jpos.iso.IFA_LLLCHAR"/>
  <isofield
      id="120"
      length="999"
      name="Reserved for national use"
      class="org.jpos.iso.IFA_LLLCHAR"/>
  <isofield
      id="121"
      length="999"
      name="Reserved for national use"
      class="org.jpos.iso.IFA_LLLCHAR"/>
  <isofield
      id="122"
      length="999"
      name="Reserved for national use"
      class="org.jpos.iso.IFA_LLLCHAR"/>
  <isofield
      id="123"
      length="999"
      name="Reserved for private use"
      class="org.jpos.iso.IFA_LLLCHAR"/>
  <isofield
      id="124"
      length="999"
      name="Reserved for private use"
      class="org.jpos.iso.IFA_LLLCHAR"/>
  <isofield
      id="125"
      length="999"
      name="Reserved for private use"
      class="org.jpos.iso.IFA_LLLCHAR"/>
  <isofield
      id="126"
      length="999"
      name="Reserved for private use"
      class="org.jpos.iso.IFA_LLLCHAR"/>
  <isofield
      id="127"
      length="999"
      name="Reserved for private use"
      class="org.jpos.iso.IFA_LLLCHAR"/>
  <isofield
      id="128"
      length="8"
      name="Message authentication code field"
      class="org.jpos.iso.IFA_BINARY"/>
</isopackager>
```

And the logs are:

```
<log realm="client" at="2024-01-02T14:43:40.881" lifespan="7ms">
  <pack>
    3138303430303330303130303030303030303030313134383339323430313032313434333430383331
  </pack>
</log>
Message Hex Dump:: 
3138303430303330303130303030303030303030313134383339323430313032313434333430383331
Message ASCII Dump:: 
18040030010000000000114839240102144340831
<log realm="client/172.20.30.50:6320" at="2024-01-02T14:43:41.005" lifespan="119ms">
  <connect>
    Try 0 172.xx.xx.xx:63xx
      Connection established to 172.xx.xx.xx:63xx
  </connect>
</log>
<log realm="client" at="2024-01-02T14:43:41.005">
  <pack>
    3138303430303330303130303030303030303030313134383339323430313032313434333430383331
  </pack>
</log>
<log realm="client/172.xx.xx.xx:63xx" at="2024-01-02T14:43:41.005">
  <send>
    <isomsg direction="outgoing">
      <!-- org.jpos.iso.packager.GenericPackager -->
      <field id="0" value="1804"/>
      <field id="11" value="114839"/>
      <field id="12" value="240102144340"/>
      <field id="24" value="831"/>
    </isomsg>
  </send>
</log>
```

What am I actually doing wrong, your suport in this regards highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The channel handles the length header for you. What you are actually setting with

```java
        // Prepare the header
        byte[] header = new byte[2];
        int length = packedMessage.length + 2;
        header[0] = (byte) (length >> 8); // High byte
        header[1] = (byte) (length);      // Low byte
```

Is the message header, which is a header that goes after the length header, an it seems it is not needed as per the shared spec.

It seems you need a `PostChannel`, the code would be something like this:

```java
        // Load the ISO 8583 packager
        ISOPackager packager = new GenericPackager("jar:iso93ascii.xml"); //jPOS can load the packager for you

        // Create an ASCIIChannel (use appropriate channel as per your requirement) the appropriate channel seems to be PostChannel

        ISOChannel channel = new PostChannel(serverIP, serverPort, packager);

        // Connect to the server
        channel.connect();
        System.out.println("Connected to server: " + serverIP + ":" + serverPort);

        // Sending Network Management Request
        ISOMsg isoMsg = new ISOMsg();
        //channel will set the packager
        isoMsg.setMTI("1804");
        String stan = TransactionUtils.generateSTAN();
        System.out.println(stan + " -> length : " + stan.length() );
        isoMsg.set(11, stan); // Unique STAN
        String datetime = new SimpleDateFormat("yyMMddHHmmss").format(new Date());
        System.out.println(datetime + " -> length : " + datetime.length());
        isoMsg.set(12, datetime); // yyMMddHHmmss
        isoMsg.set(24, "831"); // Function code

        channel.send(isoMsg);
        System.out.println("ISO Network Management Call Sent...");

        ISOMsg response = channel.receive();
        System.out.println("Received Network Management Response from the Server!");
        printISOMessage(response);
```

If you want to know what goes over the TCP/IP stream you better use a sniffer like tcpdump or Wireshark. You can set a logger to the packager to check the packaged message.

I'm on mobile and will expand later, but you also should consider using Q2 to configure the channel.

Comment: I tried your suggested changes but the behaviour, no response from server side.

Comment: Though I appreciate your quick response. Thanks

Comment: Well, there are lots of other things to consider, like if the packager is correct, but didn`t this fix the issue about the header? which was your question? If not, please elaborate and adjust your question.

Comment: Server side team said they are expecting "Header Type = BCH Encoding" and "Header Length = 2" and "big endian bytes = true"

Comment: And what are they receiving, can you show an hex dump (expected and real) so we know the difference between what is being received and what is being expected?, please add those details to the question. Is it "BCH encoding"  or "BCD Encoding" I don't know such thing as a BCH encoding. Given how you tried to set the header, it would seem that it's just two plain bytes.

Comment: If it is BCD, you may need `BCDChannel` instead of `PostChannel`. But please, add an example hex dump of an encoded length to the question, so we know for sure and can help you better.

Comment: Ok so it's SmartVista implementation. I have tried appending the header. and hex after packed as is `00293138303430303330303130303030303030303030313134383339323430313032303931343536383331`. I feel there is some issue with my header as they have requested BCH (Binary Encoded Hexadecimal) value and the bitmap calculation.

Comment: I have updated my question, with header requirement specifically be shared by my client. I believe it's binary encoded hexadecimal value.

Comment: Ok, if what they are expecting is Binary encoded decimal, and binary encoded decimal means what I think it means (I couldn't find any official definition on that) the code I provided should work. If it doesn't, you need to ask the server side, exactly what they are expecting (hex representation of the raw data they are expecting as header, better if they include until the MTI at least) and what they are receiving, with this code. This is the only way I see we could help you advance.

Comment: Upon request this is what client has shared. Ahsan here is a dump of proper request. 
0021313830340030010000000000393538313431323430313033313031353030383331

the response 
0024313831340030010002000000393538313431323430313033313031353030383331303030
length in hexadecimal (0021) + MTI in hex string (31383034) + binary bitmap as hexbytes (0030010000000000) + content  in hex string (393538313431323430313033313031353030383331)

21  => 36 decimal (bytes) 
There are 36*2 (72) characters in the content. Why? because in hex string, each character is represented as two bytes.

Comment: Ok so I have tried passing hexString as per their provided sample. And it worked. Now the issue is this I have to deliberately convert each field into hexString and so as increase the length in iso configuration xml. Is there any automated manner of getting this done?

Comment: You need to choose the correct packager, how or why did you choose the one you chose? I'm also not sure what you mean by "Now the issue is this I have to deliberately convert each field into hexString and so as increase the length in iso configuration xml" you always have to check field by field if the packager matches the specification.

Comment: But first things first, are they receiving the correct length of the packaged message, as generated by the packager?